# if(x % y == 0) is causing my program to not output anything?

Tags: c++

Currently working on the third problem of project euler and stumbled upon a strange issue that's had me banging my head against a wall trying to figure it out. I isolated the issue down to this small portion of code.

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    long max = 13195;
    long largestPrimeNumber = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        if(max % i == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "test\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "other test\n";
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The end goal of this little test program is for it to output "test" for every nonprime number and "another test" for every prime number less than 13195 like this:

```
test
test
test
test
another test
test
test
another test
```

I've tried methods such as putting this into a function and running the function in the for loop. It works fine until I add in the condition `(max % i == 0);`. something about it seems to mess up the code but I have no idea what.

Comment: "mess up the code" doesn't really explain what's going on.

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, `i` is 0 and trying to compute the remainder mod 0 is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

`max % i` when `i` is 0 is undefined behavior (UB) according to the C++ standard.  In my case there is an FPU exception at runtime, but the program can do *anything at all* when this situation is encountered.

In fact, the compiler is allowed to assume this will never happen, and it might draw all sorts of interesting conclusions if it notices that this happens, up to and including assuming that `main()` cannot possibly be called.  (Proof: `main()` unconditionally takes 13195 mod 0, and that cannot happen because it's UB, therefore `main()` must not be called.)

The most likely fix is starting your loop counter at 1 or some other positive number.

> The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the binary `%` operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. **If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined.**

-- N4713 [expr.mul]/4 (emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you very much! I've definitely heard a little about undefined behavior, however I've never actually encountered it before and never really learned what an example of it would be. Glad I asked or else I would've still been racking my brain on this tomorrow.

Comment: @noobCodeKid We have all been there, and even seasoned C++ developers will cause UB from time to time. It can be a _bear_ to track down, too. Check out [Piotr Padlewski's talk on UB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehyHyAIa5so) -- it demonstrates some _crazy_ things that compilers will do when they encounter UB. While they make sense, it can make debugging the problem very difficult. (Why was my complicated function reduced to a single instruction!?)